# Stopping the Magento 2 Session from clering on checkout completion

Tags: magento2, checkout

In the Magento 1 days I'd just take the file from the core Magento files and comment out the session clear function on the checkout page allowing our front end developers to refresh the page as they please without having to keep making new orders to test every new piece of CSS they wrote.

Is there any way to stop the checkout process from having to be done again and again to style the thank you page on Magento 2.1? I can't find anything when trying to Google the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out it in magento-2 from given file

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php
```

Just comment out this line :  `$session->clearQuote();`

Comment: Editing the core directly is a bad idea as you will loose your changes when you upgrade

Comment: @Raphaela it is just for temporary, only developing purpose. after developing it will revert.

Comment: well the OP does not seem to want a temporary fix

Comment: Basiclly user want use for just for minite while write css on success page. you can read qustion, what is actully question.

Comment: My bad I misread the OP question

Comment: then why minus ?

Comment: My vote is locked unless the answer is edited  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80763/317574